# How to store a price in two integers in swift

Tags: swift, ios9, nsnumberformatter

I have read that I shouldn't treat prices as `double` numbers and that I should store them as two integers.

If for example I have an input of type `246.464` in a `UITextField` how should I make it two integers?

Comment: Maybe you can find precision issues with BIG `float`, but i doubt that you'll find any issue with `double`.

Comment: What do you mean you won't find precision issues? `var y = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1; print (y == 0.3)`

Comment: also note that you cannot represent decimal part as only one integer, you also need an exponent. For example, `0.1` and `0.01` would be both represented as `0` and `1` so you need exponent (`1` and `2` respectively) to differ between them. Or you can just save integer `246464` and save the exponent `3` (number of decimal digits). That's exactly what floating point math is doing and what `NSDecimalNumber` is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget two integers, store it as [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/). That's the class specifically created for that task.

Unlike `float` or `double`, `NSDecimalNumber` uses decadic arithmetic therefore there is no loss in precision when converting between decadic to binary and viceversa.

```
let text = "246.464" // textField.text
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: text)
```